# How to retrieve integer data from database and store in variable?

Tags: java, sql

i am trying to an integer field from the product table and trying to store in the originalQty variable but there is an error.How do i store the result in an int variabe

```
public int prodQty( String prodid){
          int originalQty = 0;

    try {

        String sql="select QUANTITY from PRODUCT where productid='"+prodid+"' '";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rs.next()){
           originalQty=rs.getInt(7);

                }

        }
     catch (SQLException ex) {

    }
    System.out.println(originalQty);
    return originalQty;
     }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to get the 7th column and not the first?

Comment: The result data itemis in the 7th column of the product table @juergend

Comment: That does not matter. Use the index of the result you select.

Comment: netbeans throws exceptions even when i did with 1st column @juergend

Comment: You only have a column in your query not 7. Maybe you need `originalQty=rs.getInt(1);` or `rs.getInt(0);` if netbeans use 0 base arrays.

Comment: @AlphaBeta: The exact error message would really help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
originalQty=rs.getInt("QUANTITY");
```

And you have a quote too much in your query

```
... where productid='"+prodid+"' '";
                                 ^--------here. Remove that
```

If the input is a number you can remove the quotes entirely.

And you should actually use *Prepared Statements* that handle escaping inputs automatically and prevent SQL injections.

Comment: i debugged the code and the debugger never went into the while statement.Why is that?

Comment: Because you have no record in your DB with that `prodid`

Comment: My DB has a record for that prodid.

Comment: `while(rs.next())` could it be because of rs.next() in the while loop?

Comment: No, that should be fine.

Comment: it works after i used `Select * ` instead of `Select Quantity `

Answer (score 0):

Some advice.

1. Always use column name.
2. Use prepared statement.
3. Learn how to debug your program. That will tell you exactly why the error.